# Headless Chrome using Selenium - 401 Unauthorized access

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to automate a few tasks on a webpage.

For this I am using Python, Selenium and Google Chrome.

The webpage, which I unfortunately cannot post here, requires a username and password. I am logged in as a user in the webpage already via my normal google chrome browser.

When I run my code and try to perform the tasks in headless mode, I get a message "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials". I captured this messaged using the screenshot capture in python.
[image: Error screenshot]
However, if I do the exact same steps in normal mode (not headless) the webpage allows me to do everything because I am already logged in as a user.

From the error message, I understand that I need to be logged in. However, my question is: why does the page allow me to perform all tasks when it is in visible mode but blocks me out when in headless mode? In both cases I am logged in already via my normal google chrome browser.

Is there a way around this in headless mode?

Please find my code below:

```
import time, datetime, sys, os, openpyxl,logging
from unidecode import unidecode
start_time = time.time()
from datetime import datetime
os.system("cls")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROME_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\'+userID+'\\'+filename+'\\chromedriver.exe'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

chrome_options = Options()  
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=chrome_options)
time.sleep(1)
browser.get("*****enter URL here*****")#unfortunately I cannot show the URL here
os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and relevant _HTML_

Answer (score 2):

from https://github.com/RobCherry/docker-chromedriver#usage

> Note: ChromeDriver restricts access to local connections by default. To allow external connections, you can pass in a custom CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS environment variable. By default, this is set to 127.0.0.1, but this can by any comma separated list of IP addresses. Setting the value as empty will allow all remote connections.

```
docker run --name chromedriver -p 127.0.0.1::4444 -e CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS='' robcherry/docker-chromedriver:latest
```

the magic is: `-e CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS=''`